# Embedding Views programmatically getting argument overridden title

Tags: views

I'm embedding a View inside my custom module, using [views_embed_view](http://api.drupalize.me/api/drupal/function/views_embed_view/7)

From the docs for this function:

> Note that this function does NOT display the title of the view. If you
>   want to do that, you will need to do what this function does manually,
>   by loading the view, getting the preview and then getting
>   $view->get_title().

However, my View has no title, instead I've set my contextual filter to override the title (from the arguments in the url).
How do I get this title?

Thanks

Edit: Here is a screengrab of my contextual filter settings.  I'm actually currently using the default taxonomy_term view that comes with Views out of the box.
[image]

Comment: how is your contextual filter overriding the title?  using that logic and drupal_set_title() should do it unless I am missing something here.

Comment: May you show the code you are using for your contextual filter, or the settings you are using for that contextual filter? Without using custom code, a contextual filter doesn't change the page title.

Comment: Added screengrab of settings to original post. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I got it...

After executing the view in your code (e.g. with a $view->preview()).
You need to find the argument in the view that sets the title, and then call set_title() on it.

Here's what I did (note that I'm assuming that in the case of multiple arguments setting titles it's the last one that works, hence the array_reverse, haven't tested this yet).

```
<?php
$view = views_get_view('taxonomy_term');
$view->preview('panel_pane_1', array($tid));
foreach (array_reverse($view->argument) as $argument) {
    if ($argument->options['title_enable']) {
        $page_title = $argument->get_title();
        break;
    }
}
?>
```

Hope that helps someone else out.